# Azure Active Directory, OWIN, and ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, owin

The stock template in VS 2013 does not use OWIN with the Active Directory configuration.  Does anyone have an good example of how I am supposed to wire this up with OWIN?  I really don't want to mix the paradigms and would like to use OWIN for everything.  Do I have to use the OpenIDConnect package?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Azure AD team has published a lot of samples on Github which you can find here: https://github.com/AzureADSamples. Of these, I believe these two may be of interest to you:

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet

> This sample shows how to build a multi-tenant .Net MVC web application
>   that uses OpenID Connect to sign up and sign in users from any Azure
>   Active Directory tenant, using the ASP.Net OpenID Connect OWIN
>   middleware and the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for
>   .NET.

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet

> This sample shows how to build an MVC web application that uses Azure
>   AD for sign-in using the OpenID Connect protocol, and then calls a web
>   API under the signed-in user's identity using tokens obtained via
>   OAuth 2.0. This sample uses the OpenID Connect ASP.Net OWIN middleware
>   and ADAL .Net.

Comment: Thanks for those links. However, which one should I be using.  It seems that I have to use two different methods if I have both an API and MVC together in an app.  Neither are clear or straight forward as far as that goes.